# Setting a Parcelable as an ImageView image

Tags: java, android

I've been using this library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4072 to get images from gallary and camera to set as a profile picture.

```
    TextView chooseImageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUp_uploadPicture_textView);
    chooseImageTextView.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ImagePicker.create((Activity) SignUpActivity.this)
                            .folderMode(true)
                            .folderTitle("Select image folder")
                            .imageTitle("Select image")
                            .single()
                            .showCamera(true)
                            .imageDirectory("Camera - Bond Messenger")
                            .start(REQUEST_CODE_PICKER);
                }
            }
    );
```

and it's been working pretty fine but the result image comes as a Parcelable ArrayList of the type Image imported from library and so comes the problem here

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_SELECTED_IMAGES);

        profilePictureCircleImageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(0));
    }
}
```

I get an error trying to set the result Image as in Image for the profilePictureCircleImageView

so i've tried casting it to Bitmap, BitmapDrawable and Drawable but none worked

so any help please? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick digging into the source code of your provided library reveals that the `Image` class is not from the android package `android.media.Image`.

[See Image.class from library on github](https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker/blob/master/imagepicker/src/main/java/com/nguyenhoanglam/imagepicker/model/Image.java)

So since the class holds the path of the image you can do the following.

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images.get(0).getPath());
profilePictureCircleImageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is returned is not the actual image, but an Objects that holds the image's path.
You'll have to load it manually:

```
String path = images.get(i).getPath()

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, null);

profilePictureCircleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```